# Spark JDBC connection to ClickHouse gives "No suitable driver" and "NoClassDefFoundError" errors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jdbc, clickhouse

I am trying to establish a JDBC connection between Spark and ClickHouse using the ClickHouse JDBC driver. However, I am encountering the following errors:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o101.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver
```

Here's the relevant code snippet I'm using:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ClickHouse Example") \
    .master("spark://spark-master:7077") \
    .config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "/opt/spark/jars/clickhouse-jdbc-0.4.6-all.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

properties = {
    "url": "jdbc:clickhouse://127.0.0.1:8123/clickstream_data",
    "user": "1",
    "password": "2"
}

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", properties["url"]) \
    .option("dbtable", "123") \
    .option("user", properties["user"]) \
    .option("password", properties["password"]) \
    .option("driver", "ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver") \
    .load()
```

I have already downloaded the ClickHouse JDBC driver (clickhouse-jdbc-0.4.6-all.jar) and placed it in the correct directory (/opt/spark/jars/). However, it seems like the driver is not being recognized or there is a compatibility issue.

What could be causing these errors, and how can I resolve them? Are there any additional steps or configurations I need to perform to establish a successful JDBC connection between Spark and ClickHouse?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you may need to customize executors class path as well

Comment: I added    .config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "/opt/spark/jars/clickhouse-jdbc-0.4.6-all.jar")  but still have same error. Maybe I need to change name of 
driver in .option? I just don't know how to setup it right

Comment: Add `--jars /opt/spark/jars/clickhouse-jdbc-0.4.6-all.jar` option to pyspark/spark-submit.

Answer (score 1):

Add the [ClickHouse Integration Spark](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.housepower/clickhouse-integration-spark) artifact jar to your launcher jars. Then add the following line before using the jdbc format.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.JdbcDialects.registerDialect(org.apache.spark.sql.jdbc.ClickHouseDialect)
```